# Can a weighted $\ell^p$ norm be bounded by an unweighted $\ell^q$ norm?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, banach-spaces, sequences-and-series, besov-spaces

For any sequence $\omega\in[1, \infty)^{\mathbb{N}}$, define the weighted $\ell^p_\omega$-norm of the sequence $v$ by
$$\Vert v\Vert_{\ell^p_\omega} := \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \omega_k^p |v|_k^p\right)^{1/p} .$$

**My question is:** If $v\in\ell^q$ and $p>q$, under which conditions on $\omega$ will $v\in\ell^p_\omega$?

---

Obviously, since $p>q$, we can use Hölder‘s inequality to bound
$$
\Vert v\Vert_{\ell^p_\omega}^p
= \Vert \omega^p v^{p-q}v^q\Vert_{\ell^1}
\le \Vert \omega^p v^{p-q}\Vert_{\ell^\infty}\Vert v^q\Vert_{\ell^1}
= \Vert \omega^{p/(p-q)} v\Vert_{\ell^\infty}^{p-q} \Vert v\Vert_{\ell^q}^q .
$$
This gives the condition $\Vert\omega^{p/(p-q)}v\Vert_{\ell^\infty} <\infty$.
(Here, all operations on the sequences have to be understood element-wise.)

- But is this condition necessary?
- Moreover, can we find an unbounded increasing sequence $\omega$ (preferably algebraically increasing like $\omega_k=k^s$ for $s=\frac1q-\frac1p$) such that $\ell^q\subseteq\ell^p_\omega$?

Comment: I don’t understand how. Since $p>q$, it always holds that $\Vert v\Vert_{\ell^p_1} = \Vert v\Vert_{\ell^p} \le \Vert v\Vert_{\ell^q}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to both questions is no.

- Taking $q=1$, $p=2$, $v_k = k^{-(1+\varepsilon)}$ and $\omega_k = k^{(1+3/2\varepsilon)/2}$ for some $\varepsilon>0$ provides a counter-example to the first assertion.
- [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2296826/303111) provides a counter-example for the second assertion when $\omega$ increases algebraically.
  It can be generalized to any explicitly given sequence $\omega$.